# Is there a way to define the sforce.Sobject's field using a javascript variable? (ajax toolkit in visualforce)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, remote-objects

As shown in the code comments below I want to use the variable "someCustomField" in the account.someCustomField statement but the error message tells me "someCustomField" doesnt exist despite its value in js logs as expected as "somefield__c".

Error: sforce.Xml {faultcode: "sf:INVALID_FIELD", faultstring: "INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'someCustomField' on ....}

Is there any way to use a js variable for a sforce.Sobject's field?

```
var someCustomField = data.value; //data.value in my case is "somefield__c"
console.log(someCustomField); //  as-expected this returns "somefield__c"


//create an account
var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
account.Name = "myName";
account.Phone = "2837484894";
account.someCustomField = "abcdefg"; // this line doesnt work, unfortunately. The error message tells me "someCustomField" doesnt exist. Is there any way to use a variable for a sforce.Sobject's field? I dont want to hardcode fields and I want to pass the field from a variable.
result = sforce.connection.create([account]);

//update that account
account.id = result[0].id;
account.Phone = "12398238";
result = sforce.connection.update([account]);

if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
  log("account with id " + result[0].id + " updated");
} else {
  log("failed to update account " + result[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure -

```
account[someCustomField] = "abcdefg"
```